# Beego ORM with MySQL

Tags: go, beego

I am new to Beego as well as Go. I read its documentation but it puts every ORM operation in the main package instead of model package. I can't understand how to organize the code. I am really very confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can feel free to follow steps as below, and try to build your first database program.

1. Build [Models] 
   According to the table structure of your database.
2. Initialize the ORM
3. New an ORM instance
4. Operate CRUD as your want

Link:
Guidance for Beego/orm configuration
https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/orm.md

Guidance for operating CRUD on Beego/orm
https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/object.md